# How to iterate over all items in jqGrid cache

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using the `loadonce` option with jqGrid to pull data from a database.  The number of records is not too large (couple hundred) but too big to see on the entire screen.  As is I have to use pagination.  How do I iterate through all records that are on the client?  I know I can use `getDataIDs` but that only gives me all of the records that are on the screen at one time.  I've looked but I've yet to find a way to see all data other than on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the local data by the code like

```
var gridData = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
```

To get all ids of the rows and the corresponding indexes in the `gridData` array you can use

```
var idsToDataIndexes = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index');
```

The ids of the grid will be the properties of `idsToDataIndexes` (enumerable by `for (var id in idsToDataIndexes)`) and the values of the property are the indexes in the `gridData` array.

Comment: can we iterate over the data like this: for (var i in gridData){...}  without idsToDataIndexes ?

Comment: @kozla13: If you need *only data, without its rowid*, then you can iterate over the array `gridData`. Nevertheless the usage of `for (var i in gridData){...}` would be very bad. JavaScript have it's rules and object inheritance. You should use `var i, l = gridData.length; for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {.../*one can use gridData[i] here*/...}`